# Separating two select boxes on same row equally in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container that is a certain width.

I have two select elements rendering on the same line in this `main div container`. The first one is absolute positioned 40px left from the `main div container` and the right one is absolute positioned 40px right from the `main div container`. Thus, resulting in a centered container within the `main div container`.

**My goal is to push two select elements into the resulting container that sit on either side of either, having the same width, and having a space equidistant in the middle.**

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <select class="edit" style="left: 40px; top: 290px; width: 136px;"></select>
    <select class="edit" style="left: 190px; right:40px; top: 290px; width: 136px"></select>
</div>
```

So in this one we are assuming that the left has a combined pixel count of `40+136=176px, width plus left positioning` and the right having a pixel count of `190+136+40=366, left positioning plus width plus right`;

**the result would be a container having two equidistant select boxes within the constraints of 40px each way.**

I'm not sure if my math is correct but any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would make two Elements `width:50%` inside `<div id='container'>`. They must have a height. `float:left:` on them. Might as well get rid of your `left` positions and make those `<select>`s `margin:0 auto;`. Use CSS instead of inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `left:190px` from the right hand element. The `right:40px` is enough to position the element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, so let me know if I've misunderstood something, but what about this solution (note that .edit could just as easily have a strictly %-based width, I just wanted to show how flexible this solution could be):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcn51a1p/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <select class="edit"></select>
    <select class="edit pull-right"></select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
   margin: 0 40px;
}

.edit {
    width: 120px;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.pull-right {
    float:right;
}
```